# Matching a string in java regex expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to use the "matches" method of the String class.
**I don't want to create a Pattern and Matcher object** and use matcher.find()
to match a specific string I am working with.

Here's my code:

```
String string = "-12Log";
if(string.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?[Log]")System.out.println("dinos");
```

I have used different types of regexes with no success.
I have used the following:

```
-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\[Log]
-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?[+a-zA-Z]
-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?+[a-zA-Z]
```

Please note that I don't want to break down the string into its characters. I would like to use the string as it is.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Remove square brackets - [`"-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?Log"`](http://ideone.com/WPEMS9). As for the number matching pattern, it can be different, depending on your requirements. Usually, the pattern looks like `\\d*\\.?\\d+`. If `Log` is a dynamic part, use `[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: Stop bringing my questions down. What was wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help everyone: found an answer already
the matcher that worked is:

```
-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?.*(Log).*
```